# How to install phpmyadmin 4.0 on Debian

Tags: debian, mysql, php

Is there a way to install an up-to-date `phpmyadin` on Debian via `apt-get`?

I only found a [PPA for Ubuntu on the](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin) that you can install with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 4):

You can download the latest version from the [official page](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) and follow the instructions inside the compressed file for the installation.

Alternatively if you want to use the debian repositories, you can add

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Also add

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=testing
Pin-Priority: 500
```

in `/etc/apt/preferences`

Doing this you'll have all the packages for the testing version, but they're not going to be installed unless you specify it, so run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install <package name>=<version>
for example

apt-get install phpmyadmin=4.0.5
```

You can check the different versions with

apt-cache showpkg phpmyadmin‍‍‍‍

OR check with this site [here](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/phpmyadmin.htm)

Glad if it works.

Comment: One thing though, you want the `unstable` not `testing`. The package in `testing` is `4.0.4.2-1` not the latest, which is `4.0.5-1` and found in `unstable`.

Comment: your description doesen't work: it would install all updates from `testing` and there is a typo in /etc/apt/source.list: it's *sources.list*

Comment: May be if you set the pin priority to 99?